# Derivative on a disconnected set

Tags: real-analysis

Is the derivative of a function defined on a disconnected set? For example if ln |sec x| were defined on an interval (0,pi)-{pi/2} which is a closed interval with the point pi/2 removed, then can we say that the derivative tanx exists at all points on this disconnected domain? Thanks.

Comment: Yes sure.  Why not?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The reason I ask this is that this leads to a seeming contradiction. The Darboux property says that all differentiable functions have a derivative with the intermediate value property but this is not so for tanx if one picked the interval (pi/3, 2pi/3) since it has a vertical asymptote at pi/2. Could you please explain this? I appreciate the help.

Comment: The Darboux property only holds for differentiable functions defined on intervals, i.e. conected domains.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Got it.